# Форматирование вывода строки в Django

Tags: python, django, slug

У меня возникла проблема с выводом данных "slug" на итоговую страницу.
Мне необходимо выводить данные slug'ов на страницу через запятую следующим примером:

```
комедия, приключения, романтика, фентези
```

Однако же данные выводятся в следующем формате:

```
к,о,м,е,д,и,я п,р,и,к,л,ю,ч,е,н,и,я р,о,м,а,н,т,и,к,а ф,э,н,т,е,з,и
```

Как можно исправить данную ситуацию?

Шаблон:

```
<strong>Жанры:</strong> 
{% for item in card.janre.all %}
{{ item.title|join:"," }}  
{% endfor %}
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class Card(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Наименование')
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, verbose_name='Тег')
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Картинка')
  header = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Заголовок')
  body = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Описание')
  rating = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name='Рейтинг')
  date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=False, verbose_name='Дата выхода')
  janre = models.ManyToManyField('Janre', blank=True, related_name='cards', verbose_name='Жанр')
  is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
  
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('card_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

  def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.title)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name= 'Карточка' 
    verbose_name_plural= 'Карточки' 
    ordering=['header']

class Janre(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, verbose_name='Наименование жанра')
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Тег')
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Картинка жанра')
  
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('janre_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

  def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.title)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name= 'Жанр' 
    verbose_name_plural= 'Жанры' 
    ordering=['title']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Card, Janre

def card_page(request):
  cards = Card.objects.all()
  return render(request, template_name='cards/card_page.html', context={'cards': cards})

# CBV - class based view
# Получает slug'и и возвращает данные по ключу
class CardDetail(View): 
  def get(self, request, slug):
    card = Card.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    return render(request, template_name='cards/card_detail.html', context={'card': card})

class JanreDetail(View):
  def get(self, request, slug):
    janre = Janre.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    return render(request, template_name='cards/janre_detail.html', context={'janre': janre})

def janres_page(request):
  janres = Janre.objects.all()
  return render(request, template_name='cards/janres_page.html', context={'janres': janres})

# def janre_detail(request, slug):
#   janre = Janre.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
#   return render(request, template_name='cards/janre_detail.html', context={'janre': janre})

def about(request):
  return render(request, template_name='cards/about.html')
```

Вывод:
[image: Скриншот вывода]

Comment: Код представления забыл, которое компилит шаблон и добавляет контекст

Comment: Не припоминаю как его написать... Не могли бы помочь?

Comment: class JanreDetail(View):
  def get(self, request, slug):
    janre = Janre.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    return render(request, template_name='cards/janre_detail.html', context={'janre': janre})

Comment: Добавь этот код в сам вопрос. Перед картинкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда пишете:

```
{{ item.title|join:"," }}
```

то `join` применяется к `item.title`, который трактуется как список, т.е. список символов, и соответственно `join` объеденяет список добавляя запятые меджу элементами (отдельными символами в `title`).

Вы же хотите объединить через запятые сами заголовки, поэтому правильно применять `join` на список заголовков:

```
<strong>Жанры:</strong>
{{ card.janre.all|join:"," }}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Появилась такая проблема:
Жанры: меха, спорт, сёнен, фантастика меха, спорт, сёнен, фантастика меха, спорт, сёнен, фантастика меха, спорт, сёнен, фантастика
Он выводит жанры и повторяет в количестве присвоенных жанров для карточки.